# EF5 Code First Many to Many with Migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have done this before, but for some reason cannot get it to work in EF5.

Usually it just automatically picks up when I have many to many relationships like this one...

```
public class Beer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
}

public class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Beer> Beers { get; set; }
}
```

I am wanting a RestaurantsBeers table or whatever with just RestaurantId and BeerId.

When I create it using the normal Code First way by just running the application it works.

[image: EF Working]

Using migrations though, it won't create that table.

[image: EF Not working]

I ran `Enable-Migrations` then `Add-Migration FirstDb` and finally `Update-Database`... No dice...

Also tried this...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Beer>()
            .HasMany(b => b.Restaurants)
            .WithMany(a => a.Beers)
            .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("BeerId")
                          .MapRightKey("RestaurantId")
                          .ToTable("BeersRestaurants"));
    }
```

Comment: think you need to use the foreignKey attribute on your relations, this should then pick up the many to many etc relationship.  I have always used that attribute and never run into problems anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migrations to create a new M2M relationship are not supported yet in EF5.0RC per my experience trying to track down the same issue.  Thus why it will work on standard DB creation but doesn't work with Migration features.  You can export the create SQL from the standard code first database initialization and run it manually on the migration for now.

This should be resolved when EF5.0 goes RTM but for now we have to wait it out.

Comment: Update for anyone reading this. EF 5 Code First Migrations does support M2M definitions in this manner.

Comment: As I said, it was resolved prior to the RTM release.  Thus now works, exactly as the answer stated.